# Unknown protocol error when testing a website in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When I tried to test a website. The test result was like this:

```
Thread Name: Test new22 1-1
Sample Start: 1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 841
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 841
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: unknown protocol: stagingblueridge.com


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Kindly anybody help me to resolve the above issue...

Comment: Show your HTTP request, `stagingblueridge.com` should be in server name field

Comment: Probably, you have provided protocol as "stagingblueridge.com" instead of server name field as suggested by @user7294900

Comment: can u tell me the process how i will change it

Comment: Show your test plan so that someone can help. Check protocol field in http sampler and it should not contain "stagingblueridge.com"

Comment: Kindly show your test plan so as to get idea of the whole picture.